Segmentation fault after printing function output, works line-by-line
I'm working on a chemical clustering script in Python using the following packages:

pubchempy for fetching SMILES of chemical compounds

rdkit for generating fingerprints and computing Tanimoto similarity


import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pubchempy as pcp
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import rdFingerprintGenerator
from rdkit.DataStructs import BulkTanimotoSimilarity
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage, fcluster
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform

def get_similarity_matrix(chemical_names):
    # Function to get SMILES from a chemical name
    def get_smiles(chemical_name):
        try:
            compounds = pcp.get_compounds(chemical_name, 'name')
            if compounds:
                return compounds[0].canonical_smiles
            else:
                return None
        except IndexError:
            return None  # If compound is not found
    # Convert chemical names to SMILES
    smiles_dict = {name: get_smiles(name) for name in chemical_names}
    # Remove compounds that could not be converted to SMILES
    smiles_dict = {name: smiles for name, smiles in smiles_dict.items() if smiles}
    # Generate Morgan fingerprints
    morgan_gen = rdFingerprintGenerator.GetMorganGenerator(radius=2)
    fingerprints = {name: morgan_gen.GetFingerprint(Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)) for name, smiles in smiles_dict.items()}
    # Create a similarity matrix
    similarity_matrix = pd.DataFrame(index=smiles_dict.keys(), columns=smiles_dict.keys())
    # Calculate pairwise Tanimoto similarities
    for i, name1 in enumerate(smiles_dict.keys()):
        for j, name2 in enumerate(smiles_dict.keys()):
            if i <= j:  # To avoid redundant calculation
                if name1 == name2:
                    similarity = 1.0  # Similarity with itself
                else:
                    similarity = BulkTanimotoSimilarity(fingerprints[name1], [fingerprints[name2]])[0]
                similarity_matrix.at[name1, name2] = similarity
                similarity_matrix.at[name2, name1] = similarity  # Symmetric matrix
    return similarity_matrix


def cluster_chemicals(similarity_matrix: pd.DataFrame, threshold: float) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # Convert the similarity matrix to a distance matrix (1 - similarity)
    distance_matrix = 1.0 - similarity_matrix
    # Convert the distance matrix to a condensed distance matrix (required by linkage)
    condensed_distance_matrix = squareform(distance_matrix)
    # Perform hierarchical clustering
    Z = linkage(condensed_distance_matrix, method='average')
    # Assign cluster labels based on the similarity threshold
    clusters = fcluster(Z, threshold, criterion='distance')
    # All compounds initially belong to one cluster (cluster 0)
    initial_cluster = np.zeros(len(similarity_matrix), dtype=np.int32)
    # Ensure compounds that do not cluster with others are placed in separate clusters
    unique_clusters = np.unique(clusters)
    new_cluster_id = 1
    for cluster in unique_clusters:
        cluster_indices = np.where(clusters == cluster)[0]
        if len(cluster_indices) == 1:
            initial_cluster[cluster_indices] = 0  # Keep them in the initial cluster 0
        else:
            initial_cluster[cluster_indices] = new_cluster_id  # Assign new cluster ID
            new_cluster_id += 1
    # Create a DataFrame to display the results
    clustered_chemicals = pd.DataFrame({
        'Compound': similarity_matrix.index,
        'Cluster': initial_cluster
    })
    return clustered_chemicals



chemical_names = np.array(['Pioglitazone', 'Ticlopidine', 'Troglitazone', 'Zolpidem', 
                           'Clopidogrel', 'Clomiphene', 'Alpidem', 'Sitaxentan',
                           'Rosiglitazone', 'Ambrisentan', 'Cyclofenil', 'Minocycline',
                           'Entacapone', 'Tolcapone', 'Ibufenac', 'Ibuprofen', 'Olanzapine',
                           'Clozapine', 'Trovafloxacin', 'Bosentan'], dtype=object)
compounds_similarity = get_similarity_matrix(chemical_names)

print(chemical_names)
print(compounds_similarity)

compounds_clustered = cluster_chemicals(similarity_matrix=compounds_similarity, threshold=0.5)
print(compounds_clustered)

Python crashes with a segmentation fault (zsh: segmentation fault) when executing the last line (print(compounds_clustered)). Oddly, when I run the lines in the cluster_chemicals function manually (line by line) and print the results, it works fine and there is no segmentation fault.
This problem was reproduced in macOS and Linux environments with the following packages:
conda list
# packages in environment at /Users/xxxxx/miniconda3/envs/PythonML:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_py-xgboost-mutex         2.0                       cpu_0
_tflow_select             2.2.0                     eigen
abseil-cpp                20211102.0           hc377ac9_0
absl-py                   2.1.0           py310hca03da5_0
aiohappyeyeballs          2.4.0           py310hca03da5_0
aiohttp                   3.10.5          py310h80987f9_0
aiosignal                 1.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
appnope                   0.1.2           py310hca03da5_1001
asttokens                 2.0.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
astunparse                1.6.3                      py_0
async-timeout             4.0.3           py310hca03da5_0
attrs                     23.1.0          py310hca03da5_0
blas                      1.0                    openblas
blinker                   1.6.2           py310hca03da5_0
boost                     1.74.0          py310hd0bb7a8_5    conda-forge
boost-cpp                 1.74.0               h32e41df_4    conda-forge
bottleneck                1.3.7           py310hbda83bc_0
brotli                    1.0.9                h80987f9_8
brotli-bin                1.0.9                h80987f9_8
brotli-python             1.0.9           py310h313beb8_8
bzip2                     1.0.8                h80987f9_6
c-ares                    1.19.1               h80987f9_0
ca-certificates           2024.8.30            hf0a4a13_0    conda-forge
cachetools                5.3.3           py310hca03da5_0
cairo                     1.16.0               h302bd0f_5
certifi                   2024.8.30          pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.17.1          py310h3eb5a62_0
chardet                   4.0.0           py310hca03da5_1003
charset-normalizer        3.3.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
click                     8.1.7           py310hca03da5_0
comm                      0.2.1           py310hca03da5_0
contourpy                 1.2.0           py310h48ca7d4_0
cryptography              41.0.3          py310h3c57c4d_0
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
debugpy                   1.6.7           py310h313beb8_0
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
exceptiongroup            1.2.0           py310hca03da5_0
executing                 0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
expat                     2.6.3                h313beb8_0
flatbuffers               24.3.25              h313beb8_0
fontconfig                2.14.1               hee714a5_2
fonttools                 4.51.0          py310h80987f9_0
freetype                  2.12.1               h1192e45_0
freetype-py               2.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
frozenlist                1.4.0           py310h80987f9_0
gast                      0.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
gettext                   0.21.0               h13f89a0_1
giflib                    5.2.1                h80987f9_3
glib                      2.78.4               h313beb8_0
glib-tools                2.78.4               h313beb8_0
google-auth               2.29.0          py310hca03da5_0
google-auth-oauthlib      0.5.2           py310hca03da5_0
google-pasta              0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
greenlet                  3.0.1           py310h313beb8_0
grpc-cpp                  1.48.2               h877324c_0
grpcio                    1.48.2          py310h877324c_0
h5py                      3.11.0          py310haafd478_0
hdf5                      1.12.1               h160e8cb_2
icu                       68.1                 hc377ac9_0
idna                      3.7             py310hca03da5_0
ipdb                      0.13.13                  pypi_0    pypi
ipykernel                 6.29.5             pyh57ce528_0    conda-forge
ipython                   8.27.0          py310hca03da5_0
jedi                      0.19.1          py310hca03da5_0
joblib                    1.4.2           py310hca03da5_0
jpeg                      9e                   h80987f9_3
jupyter_client            8.6.0           py310hca03da5_0
jupyter_core              5.7.2           py310hca03da5_0
keras                     2.12.0          py310hca03da5_0
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
kiwisolver                1.4.4           py310h313beb8_0
krb5                      1.20.1               h8380606_1
lcms2                     2.12                 hba8e193_0
lerc                      3.0                  hc377ac9_0
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                h80987f9_8
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                h80987f9_8
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                h80987f9_8
libcurl                   8.2.1                h0f1d93c_0
libcxx                    14.0.6               h848a8c0_0
libdeflate                1.17                 h80987f9_1
libedit                   3.1.20230828         h80987f9_0
libev                     4.33                 h1a28f6b_1
libffi                    3.4.4                hca03da5_1
libgfortran               5.0.0           11_3_0_hca03da5_28
libgfortran5              11.3.0              h009349e_28
libglib                   2.78.4               h0a96307_0
libiconv                  1.16                 h80987f9_3
libnghttp2                1.52.0               h10c0552_1
libopenblas               0.3.21               h269037a_0
libpng                    1.6.39               h80987f9_0
libprotobuf               3.20.3               h514c7bf_0
libsodium                 1.0.18               h1a28f6b_0
libsqlite                 3.46.0               hfb93653_0    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.10.0               h449679c_2
libtiff                   4.5.1                h313beb8_0
libwebp-base              1.3.2                h80987f9_0
libxgboost                2.1.1                h313beb8_0
libxml2                   2.10.4               h372ba2a_0
libzlib                   1.2.13               hfb2fe0b_6    conda-forge
llvm-openmp               14.0.6               hc6e5704_0
lz4-c                     1.9.4                h313beb8_1
markdown                  3.4.1           py310hca03da5_0
markupsafe                2.1.3           py310h80987f9_0
matplotlib                3.9.2           py310hca03da5_0
matplotlib-base           3.9.2           py310h7ef442a_0
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6           py310hca03da5_0
multidict                 6.0.4           py310h80987f9_0
ncurses                   6.4                  h313beb8_0
nest-asyncio              1.6.0           py310hca03da5_0
numexpr                   2.8.7           py310hecc3335_0
numpy                     1.23.5          py310hb93e574_0
numpy-base                1.23.5          py310haf87e8b_0
oauthlib                  3.2.2           py310hca03da5_0
openjpeg                  2.5.2                h54b8e55_0
openssl                   1.1.1w               h53f4e23_0    conda-forge
opt_einsum                3.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
packaging                 24.1            py310hca03da5_0
pandas                    2.2.2           py310h313beb8_0
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pcre2                     10.42                hb066dcc_1
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3
pillow                    10.4.0          py310h80987f9_0
pip                       24.2            py310hca03da5_0
pixman                    0.40.0               h1a28f6b_0
platformdirs              3.10.0          py310hca03da5_0
prompt-toolkit            3.0.43          py310hca03da5_0
prompt_toolkit            3.0.43               hd3eb1b0_0
protobuf                  3.20.3          py310h313beb8_0
psutil                    5.9.0           py310h1a28f6b_0
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2
pubchempy                 1.0.4              pyh864c0ab_2    bioconda
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
py-xgboost                2.1.1           py310hca03da5_0
pyasn1                    0.4.8              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                      py_0
pybind11-abi              4                    hd3eb1b0_1
pycairo                   1.23.0          py310hc7d53f0_0
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pygments                  2.15.1          py310hca03da5_1
pyjwt                     2.8.0           py310hca03da5_0
pyopenssl                 23.2.0          py310hca03da5_0
pyparsing                 3.1.2           py310hca03da5_0
pysocks                   1.7.1           py310hca03da5_0
python                    3.10.8          hf452327_0_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.9.0post0      py310hca03da5_2
python-flatbuffers        24.3.25         py310hca03da5_0
python-tzdata             2023.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0
python_abi                3.10                    5_cp310    conda-forge
pytz                      2024.1          py310hca03da5_0
pyzmq                     25.1.2          py310h313beb8_0
rdkit                     2022.09.1       py310hb777eea_0    conda-forge
re2                       2022.04.01           hc377ac9_0
readline                  8.2                  h1a28f6b_0
reportlab                 4.2.5           py310h493c2e1_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.32.3          py310hca03da5_0
requests-oauthlib         2.0.0           py310hca03da5_0
rlpycairo                 0.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
rsa                       4.7.2              pyhd3eb1b0_1
scikit-learn              1.5.1           py310h46d7db6_0
scipy                     1.13.1          py310hd336fd7_0
seaborn                   0.13.2          py310hca03da5_0
setuptools                75.1.0          py310hca03da5_0
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
snappy                    1.2.1                h313beb8_0
sqlalchemy                2.0.34          py310hbe2cdee_0
sqlite                    3.45.3               h80987f9_0
stack_data                0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
tensorboard               2.12.1          py310hca03da5_0
tensorboard-data-server   0.7.0           py310ha6e5c4f_1
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.1           py310hca03da5_0
tensorflow                2.12.0          eigen_py310h205ab9b_0
tensorflow-base           2.12.0          eigen_py310h0a52ebb_0
tensorflow-estimator      2.12.0          py310hca03da5_0
termcolor                 2.1.0           py310hca03da5_0
threadpoolctl             3.5.0           py310h33ce5c2_0
tk                        8.6.14               h6ba3021_0
tomli                     2.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
tornado                   6.4.1           py310h80987f9_0
traitlets                 5.14.3          py310hca03da5_0
typing-extensions         4.11.0          py310hca03da5_0
typing_extensions         4.11.0          py310hca03da5_0
tzdata                    2024b                h04d1e81_0
unicodedata2              15.1.0          py310h80987f9_0
urllib3                   2.2.3           py310hca03da5_0
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
werkzeug                  3.0.3           py310hca03da5_0
wheel                     0.35.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
wrapt                     1.14.1          py310h1a28f6b_0
xgboost                   2.1.1           py310hca03da5_0
xz                        5.4.6                h80987f9_1
yarl                      1.11.0          py310h80987f9_0
zeromq                    4.3.5                h313beb8_0
zlib                      1.2.13               hfb2fe0b_6    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.6                hfb09047_0

Does anyone know what could be causing the segmentation fault?

Does it also crash if you try print(compounds_clustered.to_string())?

@matszwecja It prints it well, thank you for your suggestion! So it is just a printing issue?

Segfaults usually mean that something is wrong with C side code, which pandas uses to speed up its operations. I suggested a workaround that was mentioned for similiar issue here. That issue was fixed, but you could consider reporting this as a new issue in pandas repo.
